# Exception handling for DB Failure not working as intended

Tags: apache-camel

I am developing a small camel application which reads data from a file and write data into a DB. It's working fine. Now, I want to add DB **fail-over** feature in it which means that while writing data into DB, if the DB is unavailable due to some network failure (or someone has shut-down the DB), my application should retry for say 5 times with an interval of 1000 ms and if by that time the DB is up or (network connection is re-established) the application should continue or if the DB is not recovered by that time, the application should be shut-down.
Now, I initially tried with camel's re-delivery feature but the problem here is even if the DB recovers within 5 retries, the existing DB connection is already invalidated and hence the application could not continue with it. So, I tried to write my own class to handle this recoverable error.

The RouteBuilder looks like:

```
   public class MyRouteBuilder extends SpringRouteBuilder {
       @Override
       public void configure() throws Exception {
         registerExceptionHandler();
         addRoute();
       }

       private addRoute() {
         from("file:/DHBSI/data/input?fileName=whdh90151.csv")
         .id("MyRoute") 
         .policy(transactionRequiredPolicy)
         .process(new Processor() {
          @Override
          public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            ...
            StudentJPAEntity student = new StudentJPAEntity ();
            ...
            studentJPARepository.save(student);
          }
        }).end();
       }

       private registerExceptionHandler() {
         onException(JDBCConnectionException.class, 
           SocketException.class)
           .process(new RecoverableExceptionHandlingStrategy());

         onException(Exception.class)
           .process(new Processor() {
             @Override
             public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
               System.exit(-1);
             }
           });
       }
   }
```

`transactionRequiredPolicy` uses the same JPATransactionManager which is being used for `studentJPARepository.save(student);`

Suppose, the RecoverableExceptionHandlingStrategy looks like:

```
    public class RecoverableExceptionHandlingStrategy implements Processor {
        static int count = 0; 
        static int maxCount = 5;

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
          count++;
          if(count<=maxCount) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
          } else {
            System.exit(-1);
          }
        }
    }
```

Now while keeping the debug point at `studentJPARepository.save(student);`, I have shut down the DB service. After I release the debug point, the application is getting SocketException and as expected, goes to `process` method of `RecoverableExceptionHandlingStrategy`. But, then the route just halts and nothing happens (not coming to the debug point of `studentJPARepository.save(student);` or within `process` method of `RecoverableExceptionHandlingStrategy` for the second time. Neither the route shuts-down). Looks like, since camel is unable to rollback the exchange properly, it just halts there. Can anyone tell me what's exactly gone wrong and how I can make it work?

I am getting following error in the log:

[2020-06-09 15:05:51,183]-[ERROR]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.rollbackOnException():171]-Application exception overridden by rollback exception
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException.wrapRuntimeCamelException(RuntimeCamelException.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionErrorHandler.java:196)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:36)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.doInTransactionTemplate(TransactionErrorHandler.java:182)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processInTransaction(TransactionErrorHandler.java:140)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:107)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:116)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:228)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.doProcess(Pipeline.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.lambda$process$1(Pipeline.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$3.run(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:116)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:185)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:228)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:454)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:223)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:186)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:183)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:770)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:557)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.mumss.dhb.core.audit.impl.DefaultAuditInterfacePersister.persistIncomingAudit(DefaultAuditInterfacePersister.java:219)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ObjectHelper.invokeMethodSafe(ObjectHelper.java:207)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:421)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:242)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:213)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.AbstractBeanProcessor.process(AbstractBeanProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryState.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:476)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:185)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleSync(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.camel.spi.ReactiveExecutor.scheduleSync(ReactiveExecutor.java:66)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:146)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:203)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.doProcess(Pipeline.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.lambda$null$2(Pipeline.java:104)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$3.run(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:116)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:185)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.spi.ReactiveExecutor.schedule(ReactiveExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.callback(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:100)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.lambda$process$0(CamelInternalProcessor.java:183)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:210)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.doProcess(Pipeline.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.lambda$null$2(Pipeline.java:104)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$3.run(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:116)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:185)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.spi.ReactiveExecutor.schedule(ReactiveExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.callback(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:100)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.lambda$process$0(CamelInternalProcessor.java:183)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:210)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.doProcess(Pipeline.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.lambda$process$0(Pipeline.java:84)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$3.run(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:116)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:185)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleSync(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:84)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryState.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:476)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:185)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleSync(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.camel.spi.ReactiveExecutor.scheduleSync(ReactiveExecutor.java:66)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.access$301(TransactionErrorHandler.java:44)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler$2.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:228)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processByErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandler.java:225)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:116)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryState.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:476)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:185)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleSync(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.camel.spi.ReactiveExecutor.scheduleSync(ReactiveExecutor.java:66)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.access$301(TransactionErrorHandler.java:44)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler$2.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:228)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processByErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandler.java:225)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionErrorHandler.java:189)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2292)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2410)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4396)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4386)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:537)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1176)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1165)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2100(SessionImpl.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2776)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(SessionImpl.java:2757)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:2713)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2757)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:978)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:783)
    ... 121 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2924)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.write(IOBuffer.java:2045)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter.flush(IOBuffer.java:4146)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter.writePacket(IOBuffer.java:4048)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter.endMessage(IOBuffer.java:3185)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:7556)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:592)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:524)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2979)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:446)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    ... 152 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.write(IOBuffer.java:2040)
    ... 164 common frames omitted
[2020-06-09 15:05:51,185]-[WARN ]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.logTransactionRollback():276]-Transaction rollback (0x32a7c583) redelivered(false) for (MessageId: ID-KUNTALC-VM-1591695289643-0-2 on ExchangeId: ID-KUNTALC-VM-1591695289643-0-1) caught: Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to rollback against JDBC Connection
[2020-06-09 15:05:51,186]-[WARN ]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.processStrategyRollback():144]-Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy@710f2d72 for file: GenericFile[C:\DHBSI\data\input\whdh90151.csv]
[2020-06-09 15:06:06,701]-[WARN ]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions():137]-SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
[2020-06-09 15:06:06,702]-[ERROR]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions():142]-The TCP/IP connection to the host 172.16.31.22, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
[2020-06-09 15:06:06,703]-[WARN ]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.logTransactionRollback():276]-Transaction rollback (0x32a7c583) redelivered(false) for (MessageId: ID-KUNTALC-VM-1591695289643-0-4 on ExchangeId: ID-KUNTALC-VM-1591695289643-0-3) caught: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
[2020-06-09 15:06:06,704]-[WARN ]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.processStrategyRollback():144]-Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy@710f2d72 for file: GenericFile[C:\DHBSI\data\input\whdh90151.csv]
[2020-06-09 15:06:22,218]-[WARN ]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions():137]-SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
[2020-06-09 15:06:22,219]-[ERROR]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions():142]-The TCP/IP connection to the host 172.16.31.22, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
[2020-06-09 15:06:22,220]-[WARN ]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.logTransactionRollback():276]-Transaction rollback (0x32a7c583) redelivered(false) for (MessageId: ID-KUNTALC-VM-1591695289643-0-6 on ExchangeId: ID-KUNTALC-VM-1591695289643-0-5) caught: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
[2020-06-09 15:06:22,222]-[WARN ]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.processStrategyRollback():144]-Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy@710f2d72 for file: GenericFile[C:\DHBSI\data\input\whdh90151.csv]
[2020-06-09 15:06:37,734]-[WARN ]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions():137]-SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
[2020-06-09 15:06:37,735]-[ERROR]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions():142]-The TCP/IP connection to the host 172.16.31.22, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
[2020-06-09 15:06:37,736]-[WARN ]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.logTransactionRollback():276]-Transaction rollback (0x32a7c583) redelivered(false) for (MessageId: ID-KUNTALC-VM-1591695289643-0-8 on ExchangeId: ID-KUNTALC-VM-1591695289643-0-7) caught: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
[2020-06-09 15:06:37,737]-[WARN ]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.processStrategyRollback():144]-Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy@710f2d72 for file: GenericFile[C:\DHBSI\data\input\whdh90151.csv]
[2020-06-09 15:06:53,249]-[WARN ]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions():137]-SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
[2020-06-09 15:06:53,250]-[ERROR]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions():142]-The TCP/IP connection to the host 172.16.31.22, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
[2020-06-09 15:06:53,250]-[WARN ]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.logTransactionRollback():276]-Transaction rollback (0x32a7c583) redelivered(false) for (MessageId: ID-KUNTALC-VM-1591695289643-0-10 on ExchangeId: ID-KUNTALC-VM-1591695289643-0-9) caught: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
[2020-06-09 15:06:53,251]-[WARN ]-[HBSI/data/input]-[org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOnCompletion.processStrategyRollback():144]-Rollback file strategy: org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy@710f2d72 for file: GenericFile[C:\DHBSI\data\input\whdh90151.csv]

Answer (score 0):

The default value of maximumRedeliveries is 0 , if you don't specify that in onException() clause. That's why the exchange is not getting redelivered. As the exchange is not getting redelivered, so the counter in RecoverableExceptionHandlingStrategy is not getting incremented and the application is
not shutting down.

To achieve redeliveries, the exception clause should be modified as follows

```
onException(...)
.maximumRedeliveries(5)
.logRetryAttempted(true)                    ---> This will log the retries
.retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.INFO)  ---> at INFO level
.handled(true)
.process(<---- shutdown code ---->)
```

Answer (score 0):

Raju Parashar,

First of all, my intention is not to use redelivery feature of camel (please read carefully the description above to find why). Hence, I omitted the maximumRedeliveries part. Secondly, if I don't use maximumRedeliveries in onException() clause, then count will not be incremented, this statement is not true. I have tried with exception other than SocketException also (like InvalidInputData exception in onException clause, where rollback is happening perfectly) and there the count is incremented as expected although I did not mention maximumRedeliveries clause. The problem, I suppose, is that since the DB is down in my case, while rolling back (which is a part of exception handling) camel gets exception and just waits there for the resource (DB) to recover.

Comment: I am not sure why you're not using camel's powerful redelivery mechanism. If it's because of stale connections, then I think you should check with your connection pool propertes. If connection is stale, then also you will get an exception during commit, you can handle that accordingly.

Comment: Also, If you're sure that your connection pool doesn't evict stale connections, then you should shutdown your application and don't bother about retries and redeliveries. The main point is your application's behaviour should be consistent in any case, even if you shutdown.